# Studying the convergence of the integral $\int_0^\pi \frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Studying the convergence of the integral $$\int_0^\pi \frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{x}dx$$

I'm studying for an exam in calculus and I saw this problem and I'm having trouble showing that this integral diverges (That's what says in the solution )
I tried separating the integral like this $$\int_0^\pi \frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{x}dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{x}dx+\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^\pi\frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{x}dx$$

Then I substituted $x=\pi-t$ for the second integral and I get

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{x}dx=\pi\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{x(\pi-x)}dx$$

But I don't know how to procede.

I also tried a different method with the limit test but I don't know with what function to compare. Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: The function is not bounded in the interval 0 to pi. You cannot talk about the Riemann integral in the first place.

Comment: I think your integral does not converge

Comment: I know it doesn't but I don't  know how to prove it

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner That's the whole (stated) point of the question: "*I'm having trouble showing that this integral diverges*"

Comment: @J.Dane Are you talking about Lebesgue integral? Also, do you know how to show (say) that $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x}dx$ diverges?

Comment: @ClementC. I didn't know that it mattered for what integral I'm talking about. If so, should I approach it differently? In the text, it doesn't say anything. And yes I know how to show that that integral diverges by substitution

Comment: As mentioned above, your function is not bounded, and thus not Riemann integrable. That one is quick. For Lebesgue: comparing your function to $\frac{\ln x}{x}$ is an option, since $\ln(\sin x) = \ln(x+o(x^2)) = \ln x + o(x)$ when $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume it's an improper integral (from both sides). So let's split it into two integrals as you did and let's show that the first integral on RHS
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{x}dx
$$
doesn't converge.

The integrand is negative and we know $\sin x < x$ for $x>0$. Using the fact that $\ln x$ is increasing, we have
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{x}dx
\leq \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln(x)}{x}dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\ln \pi/2} t \, dt.
$$
The last integral obviously diverges to $-\infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this simple answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Of course, if it's done in detail, one should write improper integrals as limits of proper ones.

Comment: Yeah yeah, of course, I know that